# Linux: attach USB keyboard to augment serial console

Tags: linux, console, keyboard, serial-port

I'm using an embedded linux system who boot into a "fastboot" environment which is kind of a lite Debian distrib using busybox. The device have a touch screen and two usb port.

The configured boot script have these lines that might be related:

```
export CONSOLE=/dev/ttyAM0
setconsole $CONSOLE
stty -F $CONSOLE ospeed 115200 > /dev/null 2>&1
```

It then check for a USB drive, mount it and launch a specific filename if available to act as a USB update mechanism.

My goal is to use this script launch a touchscreen calibration utility. Problem is, this utility (not mine) check for key input coming from the console from which it was launched and plugging a USB keyboard don't work. I would also like it to accept ctrl+c to quit the utility and keep processing the rest of the boot script after completion.

If I connect an extension board to some pin-out and use a computer with putty to connect to this serial interface and send the keys from there it work, but my goal is to get this working from an USB keyboard without requiring another computer to access this console.

I know the USB keyboard is detected and drivers are properly loaded. If I launch my own C program using SDL instead and read the keyboard from there it works fine. I found out that cat /dev/event1 also give my some garbled output when pressing on the keyboard. But, as said above, the calibration utility don't accept this input, just the one coming from the console who launched it.

I guess I just need to add some line in my boot script to attach the keyboard to the console, but can't find out what. Many pages online speak about a "screen" utility, unfortunately I don't seem to have it available.

Keep in mind I'm no expert and might be looking for the wrong way to do things. Please advice if this is the case.

Comment: I see sawdust edited my post to add "replace" in the title, that's not really true, "attach" was a better term. I want the keyboard to send input to ttyAM0, not replace it.

Comment: Title has been re-edited.